# Can't find Pyro Nameserver when using Pyro-nsd

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pyro

I'm using Pyro4 with Python 2.7 on a Raspberry Pi running Wheezy

When I start the Pyro Nameserver with either

```
pyro4-ns &
```

or

```
python -m Pyro4.naming &
```

My code works as expected without any errors. However When I start the Pyro name server daemon with the follow command

```
/etc/init.d/pyro-nsd start
```

when I start the lamp_daemon.py as a background process

```
/home/pi/Wakeup-Lamp/lamp_daemon.py &
```

I get the following error

> File "/home/pi/Wakeup-Lamp/lamp_daemon.py", line 27, in 
>       nameServer = Pyro4.locateNS()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pyro4/naming.py", line 358, in locateNS
>       raise e
>   Pyro4.errors.NamingError: Failed to locate the nameserver

The lamp_daemon.py code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from current_lamp_state import CurrentLampState
from lamp_state import LampState
from pwm import Pwm
import Pyro4
import Pyro.core
import Pyro.naming

class LampSwitch(Pyro.core.ObjBase):
  __currentLampState = CurrentLampState()
  __pwm = Pwm()

  def get_lamp_state(self):
    return self.__currentLampState.get()

  def set_lamp_state(self, new_lamp_state):
    self.__currentLampState.set(new_lamp_state)
    self.__pwm.update()

lampSwitch = LampSwitch()
daemon = Pyro4.Daemon()
nameServer = Pyro4.locateNS()
uri = daemon.register(lampSwitch)
nameServer.register("lamp.daemon", uri)
daemon.requestLoop()
```

I've google quite a bit but I can't seem to resolve the problem. Does anyone have any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try running this command to see if the nameserver is running: `pyro4-nsc list`

Comment: Interesting, `/etc/init.d/pyro-nsd` status gives the result, Server process 3110 is running. However `pyro4-nsc list` gives the result, Failed to locate the name server: Failed to locate the nameserver

Comment: I haven't used the pyro-nsd yet. But I'd check the contents of that file to see how it is initializing the name server.

Comment: I think a possible issue is because the pyro-nsd script checks if python3 is installed. If it python3 is installed, it will use the python3 version of pyro4.

Answer (score 1):

If the pyro version on the server is different than that on client, the it fails to find the name server, here is a way to check the Pyro version:

**python -c "import Pyro4.constants as c; print(c.PROTOCOL_VERSION)"**

If it is not the same, then please uninstall the pyro module and reinstall it.

I faced a similar issue which was fixed when I followed the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will completely solve your problem, but here is what I learned trying to get `pyro-nsd` working with python2.7. I used Ubuntu 14.04 in this case. It may be different on the Wheezy version.

1. I installed using `sudo apt-get install pyro4` since `pyro4-nsd` is not installed via pip.
2. First thing I notice is that `pyro4-nsc list` was not recognized.
3. So then I pyro4 using `sudo pip install pyro4`.
4. Now `pyro4-nsc list` works, but I get the `Failed to locate the nameserver` error.

So I took a look at the configuration for `/etc/init.d/pyro4-nsd` and found some interesting things.

**1.**

The script checks if python3 is installed. If it is, it will use the python3 version of pyro4, which gets installed as a dependency with `sudo apt-get install pyro4`.

Here I just make it use `python2.7`.

Now `pyro4-nsc list` actually works, but I get this error: `Error: CommunicationError - cannot connect: hmac key config not symmetric`, which leads to number 2

**2.**

Next thing I notice is the `export PYRO_HMAC_KEY=12345` line in the `pyro4-nsd`.

In the `Pyro4/configuration.py` file, it seems this is only used for python3: (https://github.com/delmic/Pyro4/blob/ccea9c2870a1280010bcc56f4146bc1617ec6e8d/src/Pyro4/configuration.py#L81). See this snippet here:

```
    if self.HMAC_KEY and sys.version_info>=(3,0):
        if type(self.HMAC_KEY) is not bytes:
            self.HMAC_KEY=bytes(self.HMAC_KEY, "utf-8")     # convert to bytes
```

So, basically I just removed the `PYRO_HMAC_KEY` export line.

**3.**

Minor thing but doing `sudo service pyro4-nsd restart`, starts and then stops the service when it should stop the service and then start it.

Here is the modified pyro4-nsd file:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          pyro4-nsd
# Required-Start:    $time $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $time $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Pyro4 name server daemon
# Description:       Debian init script for pyro4-nsd (Pyro4 name server daemon)
### END INIT INFO

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    <Pyro4 NameServer Daemon Script>
#    Copyright (C) <2011>  <Pierre PACORY> - ppacory@gmail.com
# Licensed under the "MIT Software License" for inclusion in Pyro4.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------


LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
LISTEN_PORT=9999
MESSAGEDIR=/var/log/Pyro4
MESSAGELOG=/var/log/Pyro4/NameServer.log
PID=/var/run/Pyro4-NameServer.pid

# Defaults - don't touch, edit /etc/default/pyro-nsd
ENABLED=0

if [ -f /etc/default/pyro4-nsd ] ; then
        . /etc/default/pyro4-nsd
fi

if [ "$ENABLED" = "0" ]; then
    echo "pyro4-nsd: disabled, see /etc/default/pyro4-nsd"
    exit 0
fi

# Add Pyro Config
# here you can add others ...

# NOTE: Comment out PYRO_HMAC_KEY since it appears to be used only for Python3 
#export PYRO_HMAC_KEY=12345
export PYRO_LOGFILE="$MESSAGELOG"
export PYRO_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Check the script is being run by root user
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "ERROR: The $0 script must be run as root"
  exit 1
fi

# Create the PID File
touch $PID

# Detect if Python 2.x or Python 3.y is installed

# NOTE: For the use of python2.7 here
PYTHON=python2.7
[ -x /usr/bin/$PYTHON ] || PYTHON=python

case "$1" in
  start)
    # create the log directory if not exist
    [ ! -d "$MESSAGEDIR" ] && mkdir -p "$MESSAGEDIR"

    echo "Starting Pyro4 Name Server"
    # test if not already running
    if [ ! -f "/proc/$(cat $PID)/exe" ]; then
      $PYTHON -m Pyro4.naming -n "$LISTEN_ADDRESS" -p "$LISTEN_PORT" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
      echo $!>"$PID"
    else
      echo "Pyro4 Name Server already running"
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping Pyro4 Name Server"
    # test if running
    if [ -f "/proc/$(cat $PID)/exe" ]; then
      kill -9 "$(cat $PID)"
      rm -rf "$PID"
    else
      echo "Pyro4 Name Server already stopped"
    fi
    ;;
  restart)
    # Stop, then Start
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  force-reload)
    # Stop, then Start
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Gohn67 I will try that out when I get home tonight